# Spark: Conditionally replace col1 value with col2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, conditional-statements, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame i've joined with legacy data and updated data:

I would like to collapse this data so whenever an non-null value in the model_update column is available it replaces the model column value in the same row. How can this be achieved?

Data frame:

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
|id                                      |make   |model   |make_update|model_update|
+----------------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
|1234                                    |Apple  |iphone  |null       |iphone x    |
|4567                                    |Apple  |iphone  |null       |iphone 8    |
|7890                                    |Apple  |iphone  |null       |null        |
+----------------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Ideal Result:

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|id                                      |make   |model    |
+----------------------------------------+-------+---------|
|1234                                    |Apple  |iphone x |
|4567                                    |Apple  |iphone 8 |
|7890                                    |Apple  |iphone   |
+----------------------------------------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using coalesce.

df=df.withColumn("model",coalesce(col("model_update"),col("model")))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("New_Model", when($"model_update".isNull ,Model)
                                  .otherwise(model_update))
```

Where df1 is your original data frame.